# Asset pipeline and @font-face on rails(rails 3.2.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, font-face, asset-pipeline, assets

how to emebed a font using @font-face on rails:

my fonts are located in:

> /vendor/assets/stylesheets/fonts/**custom-font-lists-here**.eot

my stylesheet that contain a @font-face is inside:

> /vendor/assets/stylesheets/fonts.css

I am using this right now

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArimoRegular';
    src: url('<%= asset_path('fonts/arimo-regular-webfont.eot') %>');
    src: url('<%= asset_path('fonts/arimo-regular-webfont.eot') %>'+'?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('<%= asset_path('fonts/arimo-regular-webfont.woff') %>') format('woff'),
         url('<%= asset_path('fonts/arimo-regular-webfont.ttf') %>') format('truetype'),
         url('<%= asset_path('fonts/arimo-regular-webfont.svg') %>#ArimoRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

I wonder if this is right,

Any suggestion are welcome,
Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `fonts/` portion of the file path. The `app/assets/fonts` directory should already be included in `asset_path`, so you should be able to use this:

```
<%= asset_path('arimo-regular-webfont.eot') %>
```

I don't know why this happens, but I've heard of people having issues with the `assets/fonts` directory not being in the asset pipeline so you have to add it manually. If the above doesn't work for you, try added the directory manually by putting the following in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

Comment: I modified my fonts.css.rb and still does not work. BTW thanks for your reply.

Comment: I just modified my answer... take a look when you have a minute. Hope that helps!

Comment: `assets/fonts` only work in `app` and `lib` but not in `vendor`

Answer (score 3):

While using `asset_path` helper, you should append `.erb` to your `font.css` so it becomes `font.css.erb`. A better solution would be to use asset helpers from `sass-rails` or `less-rails` gems, in your case `font-url`.

More about it: [sass-rails features](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#features)